# Preserving Angular component variables while using *ngIf

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-directives

Below is my very slimmed down code.

---

**app.component.html**

```
<app-nav></app-nav>
<app-login *ngIf="!loggedIn"></app-login>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
  loggedIn: boolean;
  ...
  //Shared service login logic - this stuff works
  loggedIn = true;
  loggedIn = false;
```

---

**login.component.ts**

```
  email: string;
  pass: string;

  Login(){
    //Shared service login logic - passes in this.email and this.pass
    //unset password but keep email
  }
```

**login.component.html**

```
<input type="email" required [(ngModel)]="email" />
<input type="password" required [(ngModel)]="pass" />
<button type="submit"  (click)="Login()">Sign In</button>
```

---

My code works great and mostly as intended. When a user is not logged in, the `<app-login>` component is not visible and vice versa. However, it is my intent to only unset the password in the `login.component.ts` since the email `<input>` is bound to `email` using `ngModel` I would think that it would be retained.

However, when a model is deconstructed and removed from the DOM, it seems that all the local variables are unset as well. What can I do to prevent this?

Comment: You have to store the data somewhere else. Even if it was retained it would not be reliable because the user could refresh the page and allowing it to behave differently under refresh is not proper in SPA design

Comment: Note that `[(ngModel)]` keeps state in sync between a property on the attributed component and the HTML Dom it's never attached to anything else

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways to do this. You could have store the email in your app.component, use local storage or a shared service.

- Get the data from the parent component ( your app.component )

app.component.html

```
    <app-nav></app-nav>
    <app-login [email]="email" *ngIf="!loggedIn"></app-login>
```

app.component.ts

```
  loggedIn: boolean;
  ...
  //Shared service login logic - this stuff works
  loggedIn = true;
  loggedIn = false;
  //new variable
  email = ""
```

and in your login.component, add @Input into your code to get the email from the app.component.

```
@Input email;
```

- Local storage

Whenever you login, save the email in your local storage like this

```
 Login(){
      localStorage.setItem('email', email);
      // your login code
  }
```

and retrieve it later via constructor when you create the login.component again.

```
constructor(){
   this.email = localStorage.getItem('email');
}
```

- Shared service

The implementation is almost identical when using local storage, you need to set the email when you log in and retrieve it again when you create the login component again. Just make sure that you provide it in your app.module to make it a singleton.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

You can have your `login` component to have `@Output` and `@Input` and `implement` `onDestroy`. Your `@Output` will be `EventEmitter` which will send data back to your `app.component` and your `@Input` value will receive email as a param and finally inside `ngOnDestroy` you can `emit` the value of `email` to `app.component` before the component is destroyed, the variable will get updated inside the `app.component` which means the next time `login` renders, it will have the latest value thanks to `@Input` on `login.component` which accepts email as a param